# Why integer is automatically converted to string when updating/saving in DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column that is supposed to be a string. In `schema.rb` it looks something like this:

```rb
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "login_token", default: "xxxxx", null: false
end
```

But if I try to update the column, the DB accepts integers and automatically converts them to strings for some reason.

```rb
user = User.first.update(login_token: 1)
#=> true
user.login_token
#=> "1"
```

Why is this, and is it possible to add any restrictions to the DB or validations in Rails to prevent this kind of typecasting?

Comment: "is it possible to add any restrictions to the DB" - nothing to do with the DB. It all happens in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works the other way around too. If you have an integer column and pass a string, rails tries to convert it. Very useful when you, say, create a record from an html form (most everything comes as a string from the browser).

```
user_params # => { "age" => "20" }
u = User.create(user_params)
u.age # => 20
```

It's a feature/convention. I wouldn't fight it, if I were you.